# WebServer for serving images using node.js

Tags: node.js, webserver

Using the following [Node.js program](https://nodejs.org/en/) I am trying host an image named `test.png` on port number `3000`.

```
var info = 'Node server for a test';

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var file = path.join(dir, req.path.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        return res.status(403).end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).end('Not found');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});

console.log(info);    var info = 'Node server for a test';

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

var mime = {
    html: 'text/html',
    txt: 'text/plain',
    css: 'text/css',
    gif: 'image/gif',
    jpg: 'image/jpeg',
    png: 'image/png',
    svg: 'image/svg+xml',
    js: 'application/javascript'
};

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var file = path.join(dir, req.path.replace(/\/$/, '/index.html'));
    if (file.indexOf(dir + path.sep) !== 0) {
        return res.status(403).end('Forbidden');
    }
    var type = mime[path.extname(file).slice(1)] || 'text/plain';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
    s.on('open', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', type);
        s.pipe(res);
    });
    s.on('error', function () {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).end('Not found');
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});

console.log(info);
```

`test.png` is located at `/Users/myusername/testhost`.

When I open `http://localhost:3000/test.png` on Chrome, it just complains "Cannot GET /test.png" on the browser. It doesn't work even if I give the full path of the image as well. I am running this on a macOS.

**Question:**
Is the above program correct when the web sever is running on macOS or Linux? How can I server images from a macOS to a program running on a browser or application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and javaScript files, use the `express.static` built-in middleware function in express.

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can put your test.png file in public directory and load it by :

```
http://localhost:3000/test.png
```